# RC discharge in two ways, solving for time constant

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-charging

Are the two underlined equations at the bottom correct (can I calculate an equivalent resistance for the time constant)? I understand how to find voltage and current for each element at time t supplied with DC voltage. So I’m looking at discharging two ways. Are they both appropriately solved?

Also I've just understood Thevenin equivalent circuit(s) solutions to these circuits so I specifically want to know if the time constant can be calculated by an equivalence resistance. Thanks guys I'm excited about every second I'll be  a part of this forum!

[image]

Comment: The voltage equations are wrong. If you're not doing this by differential equation then use \$\small v(t)=v(\infty )+(v(0)-v(\infty ))e^{-t/\tau}\$. You need to identify the resistances through which charge and discharge occurs, and also the intial and final values of the voltage (or current if that's the variable of interest). Thevenin can help with this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely use Thevenin here.

In the discharge formulas you correctly calculated the time constant as being \$C\$ times the equivalent parallel of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$.

There is a mistake on the voltage equation though. Remember that the capacitor is discharging and that its final voltage should be zero. The correct equation should be \$ V(t)=V_0e^{\frac{-t}{R_{eq}C}}\$ instead. This same correction should carry to the current equations.

Welcome to the community! :^)